# cryptopp dll crash in string destructor

Tags: c++, encryption, destructor, stdstring, crypto++

I'm implementing encrypt/decrypt program with [Crypto++ library](https://www.cryptopp.com/#download).
I made cryptopp dll and new project refer to it.

And now, I am faced to crash problem in the std::string destructor.
Belows are my codes.

```
//Encrypt
void Encryption(std::string encryptData, std::string& outString)
{
    std::string plain, cipher, encoded, recovered;

    plain = encryptData;

    unsigned char key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);

    std::string rawKey = "testRawKey";
    hex2byte(rawKey, rawKey.length(), key);

    unsigned char iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    std::string rawIv = "testRawIV";
    hex2byte(rawIv, rawIv.length(), iv);

    encoded.clear();

    CryptoPP::StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource

    encoded.clear();

    CryptoPP::StringSource(iv, sizeof(iv), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource

    try {
        CryptoPP::CFB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter filter(e);
        filter.Put((const unsigned char*)plain.data(), plain.size());
        filter.MessageEnd();

        const size_t ret = filter.MaxRetrievable();
        cipher.resize(ret);
        filter.Get((unsigned char*)cipher.data(), cipher.size());
    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        cipher = "";
    }
    outString = cipher;
}

//Decrypt
std::string Decryption(std::string cipher)
{
    std::string plain, encoded, recovered;

    unsigned char* key = new unsigned char[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    memset(key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);

    std::string rawKey = "testRawKey";
    hex2byte(rawKey, rawKey.length(), key);

    unsigned char* iv = new unsigned char[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    memset(iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    std::string rawIv = "testRawIV";
    hex2byte(rawIv, rawIv.length(), iv);

    encoded.clear();

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss1(key, sizeof(key), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource

    encoded.clear();

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(iv, sizeof(iv), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource

    std::string plainText;

    try {
        CryptoPP::CFB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption d;

        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter filter(d);

        filter.Put((const unsigned char*)cipher.data(), cipher.size());
        filter.MessageEnd();

        const size_t ret = filter.MaxRetrievable();
        recovered.resize(ret);
        filter.Get((unsigned char*)recovered.data(), recovered.size());
    }
    catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        recovered = "";
    }
    return recovered;
}

void main()
{
    std::string result = "";
    Encryption("test", result);
    cout << result << endl;
    std::string result1 = Decryption(result);
    cout << result1 << endl;
}
```

When I run this code, I always got an error.
**heap\debug_heap.cpp Line:904
Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)**

and call stack for an error is,

**testnesteddll.exe!std::string::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator()**

According to call stack, the error was occurred on *string* destructor. This is why I think crash is occurred on *string* destructor.

Finally, I looked around my codes related to string and found out where was the problem. When I commented out where I used the **StringSource** class, the error was disappeared.
So I commented out all codes related to StringSource and then I ran it. It worked well however that was result what I don't want.

I'd like to know why this error is occurred and how can I fix it?

I am really feel hard to this problem. Would you kindly share you knowledge for this please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I think you stomped over some memory, corrupted a string, and then the string exploded when it fell out of scope. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is cryptocpp built for the same visual studio runtime as your application?

Comment: You sure `hex2byte(rawKey, rawKey.length(), key);` is valid? I'd expect that to be working on `c_str()` data, not the address of the `std::string` itself. Did you compile with maximum warnings?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I built it with debug-x64 and my application runs in the same environment.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your guidance to post. I've been modified it. And I compiled it with maximum warnings. Also I changed `hex2byte` function to use const char* not std::string. However, It didn't work. Same error was occurred.

Comment: If it's using `std::string`, which it should be in C++, then you have no need for a separate `length` argument. The way you were calling it seemed to be C style.

Comment: In `Decryption()` the size of the key (and the iv) is determined incorrectly (4 bytes, `sizeof` of a pointer). The result of the `StringSource` blocks is apparently not used at all.